# Symfony2 form_login - don't want it to redirect

Tags: php, security, model-view-controller, authentication, symfony

With symfony2's Security system, you can specify a form_login type of login as a login system under the firewall section of the security config file (see: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/security.html).

Now we have a login_path parameter and when a user tries to access a site that is secure (needs AUTHENTICATION (and later on AUTHORIZATION)) they are redirected to the login form with a HTTP 302 response. However, what I want is a normal page being returned (200) and that it would just say something like "You need to authenticate to continue.".

I don't want the redirect!!!!

I would hack through the code myself, but I cannot seem to find where form_login is implemented. Can anyone point me in the right direction, or is there a better way of doing this with Symfony2?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `use_forward: true` under `form_login` in your firewall configuration.

Comment: This isn't what I want. Because this will show the login form (without redirecting). I want to show a CUSTOM TEXT, not the login form.  
 
EDIT: 
Also, I use FOSUserBundle. And I don't want to make some custom views and change their routing. Then it would work with your way, maybe, not sure.

Comment: Sounds like you want to provide your own "entry point" -- is that what you figured out?

Comment: Yeppers. I knew about that way, I just asked if there was an integrated way for doing this.